# Detect multiple Aruco boards, python

Tags: python, aruco

Is it possible to use multiple aruco boards for pose estimation? I have tried to print out multiple boards with different IDs, but the pose estimation is confused about what target to focus on.
I want to use aruco boards because the targets are going to be outside, and Im afraid a single target will be soiled and therefore not recognized.

Comment: yes. your code is broken. [mre] is required. please take the [tour] -- a target is harder to find and its pose harder to estimate if it is _small_. you should use one big target.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.